# SSL Connections with ADODB

Tags: php, ssl, mysqli, adodb

I have a project we are about to wrap up, but just got a request from the DBA to make all our connections SSL.  So I switched the driver to mysqli in the object that turns out ADODB instances, but I don't see any native method to create secure connections.

To make things more difficult, there is a different set of certs and keys per connection type (read and write).

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The trick is to use a DSN in the
>   NewADOConnection() call (rather than
>   authenticating with a Connect() call)
>   and to use the mysqli driver. The DSN
>   syntax allows you to supply client
>   flags, and there's a mysqli flag for
>   using SSL certificates.

```
$dsn = 'mysqli://ssluser:sslpass@dbhost/test?clientflags=2048';

$dbh = NewADOConnection($dsn);

$sql = "show status like 'ssl_cipher'";
$res =& $dbh->Execute($sql);
print_r( $res->fields );
$res->Close();
$dbh->Close();
```

The answer to this question is found at:

http://mbrisby.blogspot.com/2008/06/adodb-php-mysql-ssl.html

Here is the reference to MySQL Client Flags:

http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_ClientServer_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the one with the Connect method, and clientFlags property.

```
$dbc = NewADOConnection('mysqli');
$dbc->clientFlags = CLIENT_SSL;
$this->dbc->Connect('dbhost', 'ssluser', 'sslpass', 'test');
```

Either of them would work.